# JVM crashes when using MipMaps on small textures on Windows

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, mipmaps

I'm writing some code that loads ad-hoc textures at run-time. The texture I load is specified by the user so I have no knowledge of it prior to loading it.

Some of the textures can be quite large and get scaled a lot, so I'm using `TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest` for my min filter. Hence, I load the texture with useMipMaps set to true...

```
Texture texture = new Texture(imageFile, true);
```

The issue is that on Windows my JVM dies with a fatal error if the user specifies an image that is only one pixel high.

One solution would be that I could check for this by loading the texture without MipMaps enabled in order to check the size, then reload it with MipMaps enabled if the size is greater than 1, however I'd like to avoid having to load it twice.

Is there a more efficient way to get around this issue?

Comment: Just to note: it is not the JVM dying. LibGDX will inevitably drill down to external native code which will interface with OpenGL and if that native code crashes, the JVM will crash as a result of it. The OpenGL API is not exactly known for its internal error checking, if you pass it garbage a crash will usually be the result. So the ultimate "workaround" is to find how you're triggering LibGDX to do all the wrong things in its OpenGL interfacing and fix that. Or report it as a bug to the LibGDX team.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gimby: Yes, I knew it was the native code - it was clear from the thread dump, which was how I found that it was mipmapping that was causing the issue. Libgdx uses Lwjgl, so I guess it's that project that could do with beefing up their error handling. That said, generating MipMaps for textures with a width or height of 1 is almost never going to be a useful thing to do, so as bugs go it's pretty minor.

Comment: "Almost never" - I'd just go for it and state "never ever". So in that respect, your self-answer is actually a valid solution and not a workaround in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better workaround. I can load the file once as a Pixmap, then use that to construct the texture conditionally.

Here's what I ended up with...

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(imageFile);
boolean useMipMaps = pixmap.getWidth() > 1 && pixmap.getHeight() > 1;
Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap, useMipMaps);
texture.setFilter(useMipMaps ? Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest 
                             : Texture.TextureFilter.Linear,
                  Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```